# What's the accepted "abbreviation" for the original iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I've got an [original iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3939#iphone) that I'm trying to find a case for online and searching is quite difficult. What's the accepted shorthand? I've seen 2G (which seems wrong, as that would mean 2nd Generation, which would be the iPhone 3G), and 1G, neither of which seem to yield good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the newer iPhone models, the first iPhone did not include UMTS/HSDPA - also referred to as [3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G) - but only GSM/GPRS/EDGE, which are referred to as [2G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G).

The terms 2G, 3G and 4G refer to the **x'th generation of a cellular wireless standard**.

Therefore, you can search for cases that refer to the iPhone 2G. If you want to be abosultely sure, use the model identifier number when searching: A1203.

Terms used for the first iPhone include:

- original iPhone
- iPhone 2G
- iPhone EDGE
- iPhone 1

Here's an overview of celluar standards from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G#References):

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it changes from area to area but IMO, 2G is the "accepted" abbr.

Comment: @cksum Yes. 2G refers to a whole bunch of celluar standards. See the picture I've added.